# Button That increment active SlideView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

i need to implement a button to increment the 0 values seperately for each slide view, but cant figure how

Here is the slide views
[Slide 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xus5.jpg)

[slide 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3imQ.jpg)

and here is the java code for the slider view

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public SliderAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

//Arrays
public int[] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.ic_armcircle,
        R.drawable.ic_ropejump,
        R.drawable.ic_jumpingjack,
        R.drawable.ic_burpee,
        R.drawable.ic_squat
};
public String[] slide_headings = {
        "ArmCircle",
        "RopeJump",
        "JumpingJack",
        "Burpee",
        "Squat"
};
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_headings.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view == (RelativeLayout) object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);

    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.HareketResmi);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HareketAdi);

    slideImageView.setImageResource((slide_images[position]));
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
```

}

And here is the code for slider

```
public class Slider extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager mSlideViewPager;
private LinearLayout mDotLayout;
private TextView[] mDots;
private SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;
//Tıkladıkca Artan Sayı
private int HareketSayaci = 0;
Button Saydir;
TextView Sayi;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);

    mSlideViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slideViewPager);
    mDotLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

    sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(this);

    mSlideViewPager.setAdapter((sliderAdapter));

    addDotsIndicator();

    //Tıkladıkca Artan Sayı
    Saydir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Saydir);
    Sayi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TekrarSayisi);

    Saydir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HareketSayaci ++;
            Sayi.setText(Integer.toString(HareketSayaci));
        }
    });
}
public void addDotsIndicator(){

    mDots = new TextView[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < mDots.length; i++){
        mDots[i] = new TextView(this);
        mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        mDots[i].setTextSize(35);
        mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);
    }

}
```

}

i dont know if i need to seperate the counter TextView, and how can i,

but theese are the mind bluring questions

the real question is

```
i need to code a button that increments the TextView Value when clicked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand properly what problem you have to face it but as per my understanding of your question

**you have to implement your logic on viewpager change**

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

also refer to these example of the imageslider

https://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/

https://www.sanktips.com/2017/10/01/how-to-add-dots-indicator-to-image-slider-with-viewpager-in-android-studio/

Comment: think like that you are on instagram and you are viewing a set of photos, and you want to like just one of the photos but the buttonlikes all of them,

but because it is a ViewPager i see no way to seperate the like counts

Comment: these above two methods link do not work that for your side ...?

Comment: hey bro on viewpagerchangelistnear onpageSeletected method you have to put your logic I can say garrenty 99% Work that ...